# How to check if a batch file runs and avoid a dual execute?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to make a batch script but i want to avoid a dual execution. So i have tried to check if it's running.

I used the following method but i am taking this message  `ERROR: The process "MyBatchTool" not found`

```
echo off
TITLE MyBatchTool
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
tasklist /fi "imagename eq MyBatchTool" |find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 echo "Is Running"
pause
```

Do you have a suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo off
TITLE MyBatchTool
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
tasklist /fi "imagename eq MyBatchTool" 2>nul |find ":" > nul 2>nul && (
   echo "Is not Running"
   color
)||(
    echo "Is running"

)
pause
```

Comment: @poprock - what's the problem?

Comment: you have edited your answer, i think now is ok...nope it is printing always the message `Is runnning`

Comment: Even if this code works, it still can fail if both processes are started at the same time

Comment: @jeb i start manually the processes so i think it is impossible.

Comment: Unlikly isn't impossible :-) And here you need to move the `TITLE` command behind the check else this should always find it's own process

Answer (score 1):

You could use a file lock, the lock will be removed when the batch file exits even when an error occurs.
And it's safe that only one process can hold the lock.

```
2> nul (
    9> lock.tmp 2>&1 (
    call :main
    ) || ( echo Is still runiing )
)
exit /b

:main
echo This will only run in one instance
ping -n 10 localhost
```

The first part is for creating an exclusive lock file.
The `2>nul` supresses the error message when you try to start the batch a second time while it's running.

For more examples and descriptions you could search for dbenham's posts to this topic at SO or dostips.com

Comment: could you please give me an extended example ?

Comment: Added a small example, so you can test it

Comment: Good thanx, but how can i put the lock.tmp file in an other folder and not at desktop ?

Comment: since it redirects everything to the lock-file you won't get any output. Also why not deleting the lock-file when done?

Comment: @DlanodKcud You are right, I changed the redirection streams, now you can see the normal and also error output